# NoFlo graph.json / graph.fbp to JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, json, noflo, rfb-protocol

I have a [noflo](https://noflojs.org/) graph.json.

My basic use case is

1. Generate graph.json using noflo-ui
2. Convert graph.json into a javascript(or node module) file using any means possible.
3. run the file in my own node express application.

I want to see the final compiled code in javascript. I have been searching the documentation and source code. I just couldn't locate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NoFlo doesn't compile graphs to JavaScript, but instead has a runtime that wires the graph's components up on demand.

If you want to expose the graph as a JavaScript function, you can use [noflo.asCallback](https://noflojs.org/documentation/embedding/).